# :after element is repeating

Tags: css

I used :after element to create circles, after I set position they started to repeat, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/9p4wyy8n/

```
<div class="smallslide">
  <input type="checkbox" id="slide" value="none" name="check">
  <label for="slide"><label>
```

Comment: You set the `::after` pseudo elements on `<label>` elements, and have two `<label>` elements in your document (as well as much malformed HTML, since a `<label>` cannot be nested in a `<label>`, and you have multiple unclosed elements). Why wouldn't you expect to have two pseudo-elements?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the label tag. I think this is what you wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/LymzLroj/

```
<div class="smallslide">
<input type="checkbox" id="slide" value="none" name="check"/>
<label for="slide"></label>
```

Comment: ..and the div tag is not closed either.